# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh -- Python. What does this mean?

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error, hyperbolic-function

I'm running the following calculation:

```
N = 2**15
dx = 0.1
x = np.arange(-N/2,N/2)
u0 = np.zeros([N, 1])
L = N * dx
x0 = x[1] + 2 * delta
delta = 15

while x0 < L - delta:

    l1 = 1.267;
    x0 = x0 + delta
    r = 1/(l1*np.cosh(x)**2)
    u0 = r + u0
```

Essentially, while x0< L - delta this loop will run for 2^15 points.

This works fine translated into MATLAB but python gives me this error:

> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh
> r = 1/(l1*np.cosh(x)**2)

Comment: Why do you calculate `1/(l1*np.cosh(x)**2)` over and over again? None of the variables in the expression change their value over the course of the loop. In the same vein you also don't need to define `l1` within the loop.

Comment: hmm... what do you think a suitable alternative is?

Comment: Well... not to do it. Put it outside the loop.

Comment: That doesn't seem to stop the error :(

Answer (score 1):

`cosh` grows very large:

```
In [70]: np.cosh(2**10)
<ipython-input-70-c4511154ec1e>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh
  np.cosh(2**10)
Out[70]: inf
```

Why is your `x` so wide?  For most of the range, the inverse of this `cosh` will be 0.

```
In [72]: N=2**15; x = np.arange(-N/2,N/2)
In [73]: len(x)
Out[73]: 32768
In [74]: r = 1/(np.cosh(x)**2)
<ipython-input-74-404fbe3be390>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh
  r = 1/(np.cosh(x)**2)
<ipython-input-74-404fbe3be390>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  r = 1/(np.cosh(x)**2)
In [75]: r[:10]
Out[75]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

In [77]: np.sum(r<1e-16)
Out[77]: 32729
```

Look at a +-20 range for `x`

```
In [88]: x = np.arange(-20,20)
In [89]: r = 1/(np.cosh(x)**2)
In [90]: r
Out[90]: 
array([1.69934170e-17, 1.25565312e-16, 9.27809132e-16, 6.85563373e-15,
       5.06566622e-14, 3.74304919e-13, 2.76576004e-12, 2.04363561e-11,
      ...
       1.00000000e+00, 4.19974342e-01, 7.06508249e-02, 9.86603717e-03,
       ...
       1.51005382e-10, 2.04363561e-11, 2.76576004e-12, 3.74304919e-13,
       5.06566622e-14, 6.85563373e-15, 9.27809132e-16, 1.25565312e-16])
```

### suppressing the warnings

```
In [148]: x=np.array([-2**15,-2**4,0,2**4,2**15])

In [155]: np.cosh(x)
<ipython-input-155-1e743139b88e>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh
  np.cosh(x)
Out[155]: 
array([           inf, 4.44305526e+06, 1.00000000e+00, 4.44305526e+06,
                  inf])
In [156]: 1/(np.cosh(x)**2)
<ipython-input-156-5cf76600c0c7>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh
  1/(np.cosh(x)**2)
Out[156]: 
array([0.00000000e+00, 5.06566622e-14, 1.00000000e+00, 5.06566622e-14,
       0.00000000e+00])
```

The warning does not prevent you from getting useful values.  It is a **warning**, not an **error**.

But can suppress the warning.  On way is with `errstate`:

```
In [157]: with np.errstate(over='ignore'):
     ...:     y = 1/(np.cosh(x)**2)
     ...: 
In [158]: y
Out[158]: 
array([0.00000000e+00, 5.06566622e-14, 1.00000000e+00, 5.06566622e-14,
       0.00000000e+00])
```

`np.seterr` can also be used, but it will change handling for the whole script, not just this context.  So the `with np.errstate` is preferred.

Do take time to read the docs.

```
In [159]: np.geterr()
Out[159]: {'divide': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore', 'invalid': 'warn'}
```

There is also a `warnings` module

[Why can't I suppress numpy warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347987/why-cant-i-suppress-numpy-warnings)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Don't make your `x` so large!

Comment: Even in Octave `cosh(2**10)` gives `inf`.  It may not give a warning, but the value is still large.

Comment: I thought it was related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7559595/5472354). I'm just confused that the code supposedly works in matlab.

Comment: It does work in `numpy`, but it just gives us the warning.  It's a **warning**, not an **error**.

Comment: Oh, that's right.