# Numpy returns an overflow error when handling large numbers

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error, overflow

Let me explain.

So I'm running a simulation with 2^15 points in MATLAB. Part of my initial condition is to use the

```
Sech().^2
```

Function. This works perfectly fine in MATLAB and I get an array of very useable data.

In python on the other hand, when I go

```
1/( np.cosh(x)**2 )
```

I get a runtime/ overflow error that ruins my day.

Why can MATLAB handle the code but numpy can't?

> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh
> r = 1/(np.cosh(x)**2)

The code works flawlessly when translated in MATLAB and produces exactly what I want.

Comment: Because numpy used C-ish types that can overflow. Make sure you use the right type for your array.

Comment: What is the correct type of array here? I'm a bit confused

Comment: repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590932/runtimewarning-overflow-encountered-in-cosh-python-what-does-this-mean.  @Klaus numpy is **warning** that the `cosh` returns `inf`

Comment: It's a repeat yes but I'm curious to know what the correct way to do this is. It works in MATLAB

Comment: overflow warnings can be suppressed.  MATLAB has the `sech` which goes to 0, while in numpy you have to use `cosh` as an intermediate which goes to `inf`

Comment: Do you know how?

Comment: I added a warning suppress example to my previous answer.